# Direnv not loading environment when shell starts in a directory with .envrc

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables, terminal.app, direnv

Imagine I am in a shell with the working directory set to a directory that contains an `.envrc` file. When I now open up a new tab in my terminal emulator, a new shell is launched into the same working directory as the original shell.

For some reason, the `.envrc` file is not loaded in this new shell. If manually exit the working directory and enter it again, the environment variables are then loaded.

Is there a way to make the variables load automatically when the shell is created?

I am running MacOS Mojave (10.14.4) with direnv 2.20.1, using bash as my shell. I am loading the direnv hooks through my `.bashrc`.

Comment: What is the output of `direnv status` in the original shell vs the new shell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under macOS Mojave (and probably older versions), saving a `.bashrc` has no effect. Instead, use a `.bash_profile`.

Comment: saving the hook in the `.bashrc` worked fine in Catalina

Answer (score 13):

I found in my zsh environment I needed to put export in front of each variable in .envrc

```
VAR=x
```

doesn't work

Instead, use:

```
export VAR=x
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to make the variables load automatically when the shell is created

you can add this to your .bashrc

```
eval "$(direnv hook bash)"
```

it activate a hook on at the start of your bash.
If your bashrc is not loaded look at the bash_profile / bashrc to see which calls whom.

you can try to " source ~/.bashrc" to see if its your eval command that is not well written or your bashrc not called.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This also works with zsh `eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"`

Comment: Thanks, you can try to " source ~/.bashrc"  is what helped me